# Advanced Dequeuing from Oracle in C# without polling the queue

Tags: oracle

**Update  06.01.2024 :**

Okay, so i ended up with a simplified soulution. I think my main issue, was the lack of code documentation in the Oracle DataAccess for .Net 6 framework. No methods, properties, constructors etc are documented at all.

But i found out that calling the .Dequeue() methods actially stalls the code. The code will wait until it has recieved at message to dequeue, and first continue executing code after that has happened or the connection has been closed for other reasons.

So my initial question about how to avoid polling, was never relevant in the first place, as polling is not what is happening. It's actially waiting until something is recieved/pushed to the code.

Hope this information might be helpfull for other people trying to do the same thing.

**Update End**

---

I am trying to create a Windows service, that needs to dequeue som our Oracle database, using advanced queuing (AQ).

The enqueueing and dequeueing logic works as expected. I am able to dequeue messages using the below code example. However i can only get it to work by polling the queue for records.

This means that in my code, i need to have a loop, that every 100 ms polls the queue, to see if there are new messages to dequeue. This is bad practice i think, and i would like to subscribe to the queue instead, so that my code will be notified, when new records are ready to be dequeued. I can however not find any documentation on how to do that, or if it is even possible to do this.

Any advice would be much appriciated.

The following code is correctly dequeuing messages, if any exist in the queue.

```
public void DequeueFromOracleQueue()
    {
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(_oracleConnectionString))
        {

            conn.Open();
            // Create queue

            using (var queue = new OracleAQQueue("TASCOMMOUT_Q", conn))
            {  
                    OracleTransaction txn = conn.BeginTransaction();

                    queue.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit;
                    queue.DequeueOptions.Wait = 10;
                    queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Remove;
                    queue.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;
                    queue.UdtTypeName = "TASCOMMOUT_MESSAGE_TYP";

                    OracleAQMessage deqMsg = queue.Dequeue();
                    TasComOutMessage msg = (TasComOutMessage)deqMsg.Payload;

                    // Do something with the dequeued message.
                    // Out internal Business Logic here.... 

                    // End transaction.
                    txn.Commit();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

The above code, i am currently calling from a loop every xxx ms in a windows service like shown below.

```
           protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _queueService.DequeueFromOracleQueue();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
            }

            // Wait 500 ms, and then try to dequeue next message.               
            await Task.Delay(500, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

As mentioned in the question, this works. However it is bad practise, having to poll the Oracle database every 500 ms, even if there is no records to dequeue.

I instead wish to implement a soulution, where i can subscribe to the queue, and my code will then hold an open connection to Oracle, and get notified when a new records is ready to be dequeued.

Any examples on how to implement this, will be much appriciated.